# Issue while connecting Erlport

Tags: python, python-3.x, elixir

I am using ErlPort to connect to python module in my Elixir project. It was working all fine coupleof days back. But surprisingly it stopped working and throwing the following error.
 `ErlangError) Erlang error: {:python, :"builtins.ModuleNotFoundError", 'No module named 'sloth_connect'', [' File "/mnt/c/Users/project/_build/dev/lib/erlport/priv/python3/erlport/erlang.py", line 225, in _incoming_call\n f = import(mod, {}, {}, [objects[0]])\n', ' File "/mnt/c/Users/project/_build/dev/lib/erlport/priv/python3/erlport/erlang.py", line 233, in _call_with_error_handler\n function(*args)\n']} (erlport 0.10.1) /mnt/c/Users/project/deps/erlport/src/erlport.erl:234: :erlport.call/3`

I don't have expertise in python, but trying to set project path to PYTHONPATH, but no luck.

P.S : This issue occurs when I switch the branch and again come back to the branch containing this code.
Please guide me how to resolve this issue.

If I restart the machine multiple times and reinstall python, it started working. But I switched to other branch and switch back to this branch, again the same error coming up.